# Foreign Key "breaks" after a while

Tags: mysql

After several days of application running successfully I suddenly see errors:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

If I run the SQL outside the context of the application sure enough it fails.

The data looks good and the constraints worked previously.  Further, if I drop the constraints and add them back as they were everything works again.

I have to go through and drop/add the constraints until everything works again.

Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong here or quick way to recreate all FK's quickly?

Example FK Contraints:

```
CONSTRAINT `FKC92ACD965FF39405` FOREIGN KEY (`foodItem_id`) REFERENCES `FoodItem` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FKC92ACD966C592425` FOREIGN KEY (`meal_id`) REFERENCES `Meal` (`id`)
```

Example SQL:

```
    into MealItem
    (foodItem_id, meal_id, quantity) 
    values(150, 277, 0.375)
```

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: The message indicates that the constraint is working correctly. You are trying to insert data that *violates* that constraint.

Comment: Agreed that it seems pretty straight forward - but what I don't understand why the same SQL would run after simply dropping and recreating the FK.

Comment: Most probably because some other transaction has inserted the missing parent row in the meantime.

Comment: don't think that is it.  the only thing hitting the DB is myapplication.

Comment: if i stop the application entirely and run the sql manually i get the constraint viotlation.  so with no pending transactions I drop/add the constraint and run the insert it is fine.

Comment: What exactly is causing the constraint violation, which insert - as that will tell you what is missing in a parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard of a case where InnoDB foreign keys work intermittently and need to be dropped and recreated.  And I don't recommend you adopt a habit of running unnecessary ALTER TABLE statements.

The more likely explanation is that you first tried to insert a row to `MealItem` before the referenced rows in either `FoodItem` or `Meal` have been inserted.

You can find more information on the exact foreign key constraint that was violated, by running:

```
mysql> pager less
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

Look for the subsection something like the following:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------ 
...some information about the transaction and thread context...
insert into MealItem (foodItem_id, meal_id, quantity) values(150, 277, 0.375)
Foreign key constraint fails for table `mydatabase/MealTime`:
CONSTRAINT `FKC92ACD965FF39405` FOREIGN KEY (`foodItem_id`) REFERENCES `FoodItem` (`id`),
Trying to add in child table, in index `foodItem_id` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields; ...some binary description of the row you tried to insert... 
But in parent table `mydatabase/FoodItem`, in index `PRIMARY`,the closest match we can find is record:
...some binary description of MySQL's guess at a row near the one that's missing...
```

I've mocked up this example, and omitted some of the less useful stuff.  This diagnostic information is relatively easy to read (compared to some).  From this you can discover exactly which constraint had a conflict, and which parent table is missing the needed row.

---

Re your comment:

You wouldn't happen to be using OS X and MySQL between 5.5.8 and 5.5.12?  I found the error you mention in reference to a bug that appeared in a specific version of MySQL, and only on OS X.  Details here:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60309

The bug should be fixed if you upgrade to at least 5.5.13, or preferably upgrade to the latest
(5.5.32 as of June 2013).

Comment: I did run it and I see: But the parent table `enthrive`.`Meal`
or its .ibd file does not currently exist!

Comment: I am grateful for the intro to SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; and your further explanation.   What bothers me though is that the error is saying the table or .idb file does not exist when it clearly does.   Wondering if it has something to do with Hibernate DDL auto updates.

Comment: Based on the message I found this: [link](http://developer24hours.blogspot.ca/2012/12/porting-mysql-from-ubuntu-to-macosx.html)

Comment: Thanks again Bill - I am on Mac running version 5.5.10.     Will be hard to validate cleanly as the problem wasn't a problem until a few days/restarts.  That said all signs point to this being the issue.

Comment: What is the proper way to mark your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: To the left of my answer, there's an upvote control and there should be an empty checkmark symbol.  Click the checkmark so it turns green.

Comment: Doh - the comment was actually an edit to the original response. Checked.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: FWIW, I use a Macbook too, but I run MySQL in a Linux VM using VirtualBox.  I do consulting and training for MySQL, I have visited dozens of major tech companies, and I have not once encountered anyone using OS X for production MySQL servers.  It's always better to develop and test in an environment as close as possible to production.